# How to return a promise from a component's public method?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, promises

**Situation**

I'm calling a public method from a child component. The method runs, but it's supposed to return a promise. Instead, it returns nothing.

**Code**

Parent markup:

```
<aura:component>
  <c:childComponent />
</aura:component>
```

Parent JS controller:

```
var t = component.find(child).childMethod();
t.then(function(r) {
  console.log(r);
});
```

Child markup:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:method name="childMethod" action="{!c.childMethod}" access="public" />
</aura:component>
```

Child JS controller:

```
childMethod :  function(component) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)) {
    resolve('success?');
  });
}
```

**Result**

`t` returns as `undefined`, and so `then` cannot run. I need `t` to return my promise. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show us how child and parent are related? Is it markup?

Comment: Added markup! Thanks Sebastian :-) Hope this clarifies the relationship.

Comment: Traditionally, methods do not return values back to their caller, functions do. I am fairly sure that `<aura:methods>` do not return values. While I don't know this for a fact (otherwise I would've answered the question), the naming of the feature and your own experience strongly suggest this behavior.

Comment: If you are passing information back and forth between components, you are going to need to look into using event.  There are application events and component events.  And then, in your component you are wanting the value, you will have to register the event and then handle it in your component.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I was worried that might be the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are going to need here is an event instead of a traditional promise.  I don't think those work in lightning as you would expect them to do because everything has to be self contained in the components.  So, here is what I 'think' you are asking for.

First, you will need a component event:

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Dispatched when a select has changed value">
    <aura:attribute name="values" type="String[]" description="Selected values" access="global" />
</aura:event>
```

Then, in the child component, you need to register your event, and then fire it when needed.

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:registerEvent name="valueChange" type="c:SelectChange" />

...

<ui:inputText aura:id="someInputField" change="{!c.handleChangeEvent}" />
</aura:component>
```

And then in your child component's controller:

```
handleChangeEvent : function(component, event) {
        var eventSource = event.getSource();
        var values = eventSource.get("v.value");
        var cmpEvent = component.getEvent("valueChange");
        cmpEvent.setParams({
            "values" : values
        });
        cmpEvent.fire();
    }
```

Then, in your parent component you use:

```
    <aura:handler name="valueChange" event="c:SelectChange" action="{!c.handleEvent}" />

....

<c:childComponent />
```

and in your controller

```
handleEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var value = event.getParam("values");
        var item = event.getSource();
        item.set("v.value", value);
    },
```

Cheers.  Hope this helps!